# Detect fullscreen mode of youtube in C++

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome, web, youtube

I'm looking forward of someway to detect in C++ whether the user has some web-app such as Youtube in fullscreen mode.

This way I would prevent from displaying notifications in focus an therefore not bothering the user.

**Edit1**

- Should support Windows XP SP III and later (or at least nice to have
  for Win 7 and later.)

Comment: That depends hugely on which OS and windowing system you want it to work for.

Comment: OS? Windowing system? Are you on Linux? OSX? Windows?

Comment: I've just updated my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below code is from http://www.deanlee.cn/windows/how-to-detect-whether-or-not-user-is-running-a-full-screen-program/.

```
bool IsFullScreenMode()
{
  int w = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
  int h = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN); 

  HWND hWnd = 0;
  while (hWnd = FindWindowEx(NULL, hWnd, NULL, NULL))
  {
    if (GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & WS_EX_TOPMOST)
    {
      RECT rcWindow;
      GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rcWindow);
      if ((w == (rcWindow.right - rcWindow.left)) &&
         (h == (rcWindow.bottom - rcWindow.top)))
           return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing @nihuo. I've a similar solution, despite that I tried out Deanlee's code with good results on applications with full screen mode such us "Windows Player" and "Power Point" however not with Youtube's full screen mode in Chrome navigator :(